# How to Pivot with multiple where conditions with query function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Goal:**
I'm trying to use the query function to pull data from a table that has a collection of IDs, statues, and employee names and pivot them by statuses. The referencing data consists of 3 columns, which Col A has IDs, Col B has statuses ("In Progress," "Consultation," "Require Information," and "Technical Issue'') and Col C has employee names.

And I only want to count the IDs that are as "In Progress" "Consultation" "Require Information" and "Technical Issue" for each employee even though I have other statuses such as "Finished." And I want it to be grouped by each person, so I don't want three John As if John A has more than 1 "In Progress" statuses.

Lastly, if possible, I want to be able to name the pivoting values as "In Progress" "Consultation" "Require Information" and "Technical Issue" as a label.

**Current query setup that I can come up with:**
"select C, COUNT(A) where (B = 'In Progress' OR B = 'Consultation' OR B = 'Require Information' OR B = 'Technical Issue')  GROUP BY C pivot B"

**Issue**
I'm only getting 1 employee name with only 1 status even though there are many other employees that have multiple statuses.

**End Result Should Look Like This**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate your table and your formula and the result is similar to what you expect:

Formula:

```
=QUERY(A2:C15,"select C, COUNT(A) where (B = 'In Progress' OR B = 'Consultation' OR B = 'Require Information' OR B = 'Technical Issue') GROUP BY C PIVOT B")
```

[image]

Note that the default column sorting order is **ascending** so `Consultation` appears before `In Progress`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TRIM(A2:C15),
 "select Col3,count(Col1) 
  where lower(Col2) matches 'in progress|consultation|require information|technical issue' 
  group by Col3 
  pivot Col2
  label Col3'Names'"))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! However, I'm getting a #VALUE! error. Do you know why??